# angular mat radio check if value changes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

is there an event for a mat radio group where we can detect if a value changes ? cause I wanna trigger a method or a function only if select value from the radio changes.

So for example I click botton A and the value is 0 and then i click button A again  then it should return false since the value did not change.

#html

```
  <mat-radio-group
  [(ngModel)]="filters"
  aria-label="Select an option"
  [disabled]="isLoading"
>
  <mat-radio-button
    value="1"
    (change)="onChange($event)"
  >
    A
  </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button
    (change)="onChange($event)"
    value="2"
  >
    B
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

#tscode

```
export class Something {
    
    filters: any;
    onChange(event: MatRadioChange) {
    console.log('event' , event)
    if (this.isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    if (event.value === 2) {
       this.filters = '2';
       this.callAllData();
    } else {
      this.filters = '1';
      this.callMyData();
    }
  }
```

Comment: The `(change)` output only fires when the value changes.

Comment: and what if we dont yet have a current value ? how do we set the default value to button A?

Comment: Use `[(ngModel)] ` to bind to a value that you initialize to whatever default value you want.

Comment: why is that when the radio has no value yet and when I click button a it did not return any event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two-way binding `[(ngModel)]="binding"` to update your variable as such:

```html
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <mat-radio-button [value]="0">BUTTON A</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button [value]="1">BUTTON B</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

In your case, it would be:

#html:

```html
<mat-radio-group
  [(ngModel)]="filters"
  (change)="onChange()"
  aria-label="Select an option"
  [disabled]="isLoading"
>
  <mat-radio-button value="1">
    A
  </mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="2">
    B
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

#typescript:

```js
export class Something {
    filters: any;

    onChange() {
    console.log('filters' , this.filters)
    if (this.isLoading) {
      return;
    }
    this.table.pageIndex = 0;
    if (this.filters === 2) {
       this.callAllData();
    } else {
      this.callMyData();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't call the function *onChange()*, it directly updates the variable *selectedValue*.

Comment: It's hard to help you without looking at your code

Comment: Sir a questin , how does the ngmodel helps to know if the value changes?

Comment: It doesn't, if you need to call a function when the value change, you can use (ngModelChange)="onChange()"

Comment: (ngModelChange) does not work , my angular version by the way is 12

Comment: If (ngModelChange) isn't working, you can use  `(change)="onChange()"`. Keep in mind that you don't need to update the value of your variable since `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` is doing it.

Comment: can you please check my updated code above  Sir , I am receiving an error G0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Fi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246306/discussion-between-theophile-wallez-and-diya-agastya).